# Weight of an simple AE animation

Tags: animation, video, adobe-after-effects

I was just wondering, i have never used After Effects and I have no idea how big the animations actually are in terms of KB/MB size.

I want to create a simple typographic animation, with music behind, that would last 10-15sec. Simple text, Simple animation. What would be the rough weight of such animation ?

Is there a better alternative to create a simple typographic animation for a website that will work in all browsers and wont weight a ton??

Comment: a good alternative for simple, text-based animations would be `css3`'s animation capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

The weight of your AE animation depends on the quality that you save it out as and the file dimensions.

If your end goal is to create a kinetic text animation for a website, then you should use CSS3 animations or a JS animation library.

Answer (score 1):

The weight depends on a whole lot of properties (which you haven't specified).

1. Output format:
   Are you outputting as an h.264 video?  A flash animation? FLV?  This (along with the compression level used) will be largest contributing factor to output file size.
2. Dimension - if using video, the dimensions of the video will largely impact the file size.
3. Length of animation.

---

As stated by others, using CSS3 animation would be ideal, but if you need your animations timed to the music then it probably won't work as well as you'd like.

My recommendation would be to use Adobe FlashPro if you have it (or Adobe Edge Animate).  Outputting as a canvas animation or (if you don't need mobile support) a .swf will greatly decrease your file size VS playing a video made from After Effects.